# Insecure cookie not send in Android webview

Tags: android, cookies, webview, hybrid-mobile-app

We have a hybrid app, angular js/HTML wrapped in Android native wrapper.
When a service call is made via webview , only the secure cookies are sent (set by the server) and the cookies created at UI end are not sent.
Can there be a reason.

All services are on HTTPS

Cookies are set in UI as :
$.cookie('device','mobile',{path:'/'}) and please not this works in browser over a url but does not works in Hybrid App.

Comment: how are you setting the cookies on the client side?

Comment: @SamDozor : $.cookie('device','mobile',{path:'/'})